# Spring WebFlux block Http.CONNECT method

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, netty, spring-webflux

We have some security tests around our company in which the apps are tested in different ways. One of them is to try a CONNECT like:

```
telnet localhost 8080
CONNECT http://test.com HTTP/1.1
```

and in that case to return a `400` or `405`. The existing Spring MVC apps return a `400`, but it seems that our new Spring WebFlux:`5.1.2.RELEASE` app(Netty server) return a `200`.

The first thing that I did was to shift to latest spring WebFlux version:`5.1.4.RELEASE`, and in this case the response http error code was:`404`, but was still not good enough. So I tried to:

1. Create a webFilter
2. Modify the CORS filter
3. Modify Spring Security chain

,but all these solutions failed. How'd you fix that? It would be a good idea to create a custom http handler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a custom http handler:

```
public class AppContextPathCompositeHandler extends ContextPathCompositeHandler {

public AppContextPathCompositeHandler(Map<String, ? extends HttpHandler> handlerMap) {
    super(handlerMap);
}

@Override
public Mono<Void> handle(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
    if (HttpMethod.CONNECT.name().equals(request.getMethodValue())) {
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
        return response.setComplete();
    }

    return super.handle(request, response);
}
}
```

and it was configured like:

```
@Configuration
public class NettyReactiveWebServerConfig extends NettyReactiveWebServerFactory {
@Value("${server.context-path}")
private String contextPath;

@Override
public WebServer getWebServer(HttpHandler httpHandler) {
    Map<String, HttpHandler> handlerMap = new HashMap<>();
    handlerMap.put(contextPath, httpHandler);
    return super.getWebServer(new AppContextPathCompositeHandler(handlerMap));
}
}
```